# C# How can I Learn Class that Call My Method in another Class

Tags: c#

```
public class Form1:Form
{

     public Form1()
     {

     }
     Form1_Load(object Sender,EventArgs e)
     {
           SampleClass Sample=new SampleClass();
           Sample.MyMethod();
     }
}
```

this is first class in my project and second is

Hi All

```
public class SampleClass
   {
       public void MyMethod()
       {
          //When Form1 or another class call this Method
          //I want to know it for example

         Caller.Title="Deneme";
          //
         //Unless send parametr.How Can I learn Caller class and i change it items?

       }
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

The caller will have to pass a reference to itself into the method.

```
   public void MyMethod(Form caller)
   {
     caller.Title="Deneme";
   }
```

Or if you don't want the `SampleClass` to have a strong link to the Form class - it may be in a separate assembly that doesnt reference Windows form, you could pass in an Action that gets called with the correct string passed in.

```
 Form1_Load(object Sender,EventArgs e)
 {
       SampleClass Sample=new SampleClass();
       Sample.MyMethod( title => this.Title = title );
 }
```

and

```
   public void MyMethod(Action<string> setTitle )
   {
     setTitle ("Deneme");
   }
```

---

**Edit to explain delegates**

**The Action parameter**

The Action parameter on MyMethod is essentially a variable that contains code that can be run. (It does take a little head twisting to fully understand the concept.) The `<string>` part of the type says that we can pass in a string to this code that is going to be run.

Then the line that goes

```
 setTitle ("Deneme");
```

is calling this code and passing it the text "Deneme". This is the text that you want to set the Windows title to be. Now, the `MyMethod` method actually doesnt know that it is going to be setting the Windows title to be this text. This has become the responsibility of the caller. (If you want `MyMethod` to be absolutely certain that it is setting the Title of a Form, then the first solution is the one that you want.)

**Calling**

The caller of the method calls

```
MyMethod( title => this.Title = title );
```

The parameter to MyMethod is :

```
title => this.Title = title
```

This is the code that you are passing to the Action variable. The `title` to the left of the `=>` is the variable that will have the String that is passed to it when the code is invoked, and the stuff to the right of the `=>` is the code that gets called.

So when the form calls MyMethod, it is saying I want that string and I'm going to set my title to it.

The beauty of this is that MyMethod doesn't know about the form. If you want to reuse your class when you write a Console application, you may call :

```
MyMethod ( title => Console.WriteLine (title) );
```

MyMethod doesn't need to be touched at all!

Comment: I don't see the use of your delegate example. `MyMethod` can't do anything with the delegate other than run it, and it do not get a result or anything from it. Hence it's pretty useless invocation. I suggest that you either add another example that shows the power of delegates or remove it. Remember that the OP is new to programming and delegates a bit more complex topic.

Comment: See my explanation. All MyMethod needs to do with the delegate in this case is run it, it is just passing some data back to the calling method. It is up to the caller to do what it wants with it. This is a simple example, the full power isn't going to be apparent until you realise how this can solve much more complex situations as well!

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
public class SampleClass
{
    public void MyMethod(Form sender)
    {
        sender.Text = "title";
    }
}
```

Comment: Bad example. That method would break for everything but a form. If a form is expected, use a Form parameter. *Edit:* `If you need you can use Sender.GetType()`. No. Methods built like that breaks in the future since there is no way to know what kind of objects that are supported. Use overloads instead.

Comment: @jgauffin: he tells he must call this method from classes, not only forms!!! _//When Form1 or another class call this Method_. Remove downvote, come on, my post is correct ;)

Comment: Read my edited comment. You do not give him what he wants in a well architectured manner. You just give him pain in the future.

Comment: Giving good examples is important when showing newbies how to do things and `((Form)sender).Text = "title";` is a poor example since it will throw exceptions for everything else but forms. And using `GetType()` and `if`/`switch` is a poor example too. Read my previous comment or google `Liskovs Substitution Principle`.

Comment: I will remove my down vote if you change your answer per my suggestions and explain why you do as you do.

Comment: @jgauffin: I edited my post making it simpler. The rest is in Mongus Pong post. Thanks for pointing out my fault :)